# Memory Deallocation not fully working (nodes)

Tags: c++

I have tried creating a piece of code to understand how memory de-allocation works, I have understood that for each new operator I use, I need to delete it, the piece of code that I have made seems to do so, but looking at task manager, after I run the code, initially it takes 344Kb and after creating the nodes 35.3mb and after deleting them it will go down to 3044Kb (3Mb), but not the initial memory usage which was 344Kb, I'm not sure why.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node{
public:
int value;
Node *next;
Node(int value){
    this->value = value;
    next = NULL;
}
};
int main(){
system("pause");
Node *head = new Node(999999);
Node *prev = head;
for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++){
    Node *newNode = new Node(i);
    prev->next = newNode;
    prev = newNode;
}

while (head != NULL){
    Node *toDelete = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete toDelete;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How did you measure this memory consumption?

Comment: OSes do fun things with memory. Sometimes they hold onto it for you in case you need it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operating system's memory statistics is only a rough indicator for what you're investigating. You'd be better off using and understanding a memory leak detector like the one in [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html).

Answer (score 0):

Task manager is not showing the exact memory your program consumes, operating system reserves memory as per the programs request (not the program directly allocate it), and shared libraries can also make contributions for memory usage